# Aviary image unable to download

Tags: android, photo, aviary

I am getting an error while launching the aviary editor giving

There was an error while downloading the image, please try again later.

```
Intent  newIntent = new Intent(this,FeatherActivity.class);
    newIntent.setType("image/*");
    newIntent.setData(Uri.parse(Constants.EXTRA_OUTPUT));`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem,actually it was not getting the proper path for the image that is i was not able to supply proper URI of the image,so when i was able to supply proper URI my error was gone